# Missing value handling in cforest in R

Tags: r, random-forest, missing-data, party

I'm trying to build a random forest with 100k records and 2K variables. I have an imputation process to handle missing values while using `randomForest` but I want to understand what exactly happens to missing values in predictors in `cforest`.

I looked at a tree and there were no specific actions for missing values. The code says `na.action = NULL`. Is there any imputation going on internally in `cforest` or it can handle `NA`s as separate entity? Also is it advisable to use `cforest` instead of `randomForest` to deal with missing values?

Comment: [Please don't cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33008784/missing-value-handling-in-cforestparty-in-r)